# Ask for certain credentials when trying to open a file on windows

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, credentials, username

I have a file on windows 7 and what I want to do is once someone tries to open this file I want a window to appear asking for the username and password (which is not related to the windows credentials, these credentials would be stored somewhere in another file) and depending on the username and password entered a file will be copied from one location to another. So for example, if userA logged in with passUserA then fileA will be copied to a destination folder, if userB logged in with passUserB then fileB will be the one copied to a destination folder. Any thoughts please how this can be done?

Comment: can you provide more details as to *why* you would want or need this behaviour?

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo because depending on the user-credentials I want a file to be copied in a specific location before the application runs.

Comment: I mean, what are these files you are copying and where are you copying them to? Who will be using the user credentials and what will they be accessing? What's the file that should supposedly trigger the login prompt?

Comment: The behaviour you're asking is pretty hacky. There has to be a better way to get the functionality you want without having to go through all sorts of things manually (watching for a file opening, managing user credentials, copying files, etc).

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo so I have a shortcut of a .exe of an application, when this .exe file runs it loads a start-up file saved in a certain location which is loaded in the application. So I have two start-up files and depending on the user credentials one of these start-up files will be copied to the start-up file location so when I double click on the shortcut or the exe itself I want to have this username and password input and depending on them the correct start-up file will be loaded then the application will be opened.

Comment: does it need to depend on crednetials? can't you go for `$env:username` or `$env:computername`?

Comment: @SimonS yes, it needs to be depending on the credentials which will be staticly written in a certain file.

Comment: Let the shortcut point to a PowerShell script or similar that does the setup and asks for the credentials. It will be easy to circumvent and with this setup it always will be. It would probably be cleaner to setup two shortcuts (one for each "version") and only supply the users with the ones they need. Still easy to circumvent but easier to maintain (probably).

Comment: @Seth thanks for your comment, could you explain or send me a link of how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script that does the neccessary setup and call that script using the shortcut instead of the actual executable. The script will start the executable. This will be easy to tamper with so it doesn't really provide any security. You will have to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to allow the execution of PowerShell scripts.

The script itself (saved as a `.ps1` file) could look like this:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

if ($credentials.Username -eq 'DOMAIN\User') {
    Copy-Item fromhere\startup1 tothere
} elseif {
    Copy-Item fromhere\startup2 tothere
}

MyProgram.exe
```

This script would NOT actually verify the credentials, just that the right username was chosen. You could do any number of actions this way and the user would still be able to start the executable directly if she/he wanted to.

Comment: is it possible to make this script protected so no one can edit it or see the username and password?

Comment: You can't hide the username as password if you store it in that file. What you could do is use a hash instead. That would make it a bit harder. For protection you could remove the write/change permissions for normal users from the script.